# A girl draws all the diagonals of an octagon. How many diagonals did she draw?

Tags: combinatorics

Probability question that I don't understand? It is on our assignment for probability and I can't seem to figure out how it has to do with probability or how to solve it.

Comment: This question isn't really about probability even though it came from a probability assignment ... It is likely part of a bigger question.

Comment: No, that's not a probability question, and it's so easy that even a boy could have drawn all the diagonals. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Well, a diagonal connects two non-adjacent vertices, yes? Well, how many segments can be drawn which connect two *distinct* vertices of an octagon? How many segments can be drawn which connect two *adjacent* vertices of an octagon? Now what?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following chart
$$
\begin{matrix}
\text{Sides}&\text{Diagonals}\\\hline
3&0\\
4&2\\
5&5\\
6&9
\end{matrix}
$$
It appears that the number of diagonals is increasing by $n-2$ each time (where $n$ is the number of sides of the new shape).

If you poke around a bit (writing down the sums or using linear algebra, or guessing), you get the formula
$$
\frac{1}{2}n^2-\frac{3}{2}n=\binom{n}{2}-n.
$$

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom {8}{2}=28$ pairs of vertices and $\binom {8}{1}=8$ of those are pairs of adjacent vertices, so there are $28-8=20$ pairs of non-adjacent vertices and therefore $20$ diagonals.

Probability often involves counting cases, which often involves combinatorics, which often uses various methods of counting,  such as over-counting followed by  a subtraction or a division.

A recent Q on this site was : $ 7$ teams in a tourney must play $3$ games each. How many games must be played in total? My answer was ten and one-half games.  Suppose we count $7$ teams $\times 3$ games per team$ =21$ games; We counted each game twice: Once for each team playing it.